# Lost to where I've got a missing catch? // Discord.JS

Tags: javascript, bots, discord

I've been staring at this for the past 30 minutes or so and I'm lost to as where I've failed. It's probably obvious now but I'm extremely tired and need a second pair of eyes ;-;

I've gone through my own checklist and I've exhausted most.
[image]

**CODE BELOW**

```
module.exports.exec = async (Cuckbot, message, args, level, settings, texts) => {

      const text = args.join(" ");
      if (!text) return message.channel.send("You must provide some text to appear on the image.");

      const msg = await message.channel.send("<a:loading:456928252502605834> Generating...");

      try {
        const { body } = await snekfetch.get(`https://nekobot.xyz/api/imagegen?type=changemymind&text=${encodeURIComponent(text)}`);
        message.channel.send("", { file: body.message });
        msg.edit("Done!");


}
```

Comment: Where exactly do you think you *do* have a `catch` or `finally` after the `try`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your brackets aren't balanced. You don't have a catch statement after `try`. You might have missed something when you copied your code out.

Should look like this:

```
module.exports.exec = async (Cuckbot, message, args, level, settings, texts) => {
  const text = args.join(" ");

  if (!text) return message.channel.send("You must provide some text to appear on the image.");

  const msg = await message.channel.send("<a:loading:456928252502605834> Generating...");

  try {
    const { body } = await snekfetch.get(`https://nekobot.xyz/api/imagegen?type=changemymind&text=${encodeURIComponent(text)}`);
    message.channel.send("", { file: body.message });
    msg.edit("Done!");
  } catch (err) {
    // do something with err
  }
}
```

Comment: This worked! I also completely removed `try {` as well as `msg.edit` as it wasn't needed and that also worked. Many thanks for your help though! I'll use this way instead of the work-around I just did.